# Convert string to GUID in Actionscript 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, soap, guid

I'm retrieving an GUID from a webservice with Flex.
With this GUID i have to retrieve an Username from the webservice.

The output gives me a "The key supplied is invalid. It must be of type System.Guid."

I looked everywhere for a solution, but I can't find the right answer.

Anyone?

Thanks!

edited: Is there a way to convert a string to a GUID in AS3?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll need to do this on the client. The problem is that you are sending a string to the server and that it requires an instance of System.Guid there and not a string. You can pass the string to the constructor of System.Guid to create a valid guid from the given string.